# Strange behavior with Goliath Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, goliath

I am getting crazy and maybe you can help me :)
The thing is: I have an API with Goliath, and when I am going to deploy with Capistrano on the server, if I check the log file I can see every 30 - 35 seconds this message:

```
Nov 26 14:21:24 adlooped-pro adlooped.log:  [28665:INFO] 2013-11-26 13:20:18 :: Starting server on 0.0.0.0:9201 in production mode. Watch out for stones.
```

The strange thing is that the service is running, but I cannot see in the .log the requests, only I can see Starting server .....
That doesn't happen in my localhost, but happen in the online server.
Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think that you are providing enough information to give any help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you monitoring the server with some external process? Is it possible that your API server is getting killed and restarted every 30-35 seconds? It may look like the server is up and running, but is the PID changing?

Try running the server in the foreground and see if you get any more information out as to why it's restarting.